# Top and Left with ng-style in angular.js 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

When I am using

```
<label ng-show="vm.maulanaConducted" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;"
   ng-style="{'top': vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y, 'left': vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_x, 'color': vm.cardSelectedData.color_code}">Nikaha
                        Conducted by Maulana{{vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y}}    
</label>
```

The color property is setting properly but the top and left are not getting in style when looking in developer tool. But when I directly add top and left property in style attribute then they work fine.

Comment: What is the value of vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y and vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_x?

Comment: Conducted by Maulana{{vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y}} when I print this  vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y is coming 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the values coming from the server are string that need to change in integer that's why they are not coming. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

The top and left should have the respective unit. Try adding the unit, eg

`ng-style="{'top': vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y + 'px', 'left': vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_x + 'px', 'color': vm.cardSelectedData.color_code}"`

Comment: Tried but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'top.px' : vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_y  , 'left.px' :  vm.cardSelectedData.nikah_x}"
```

Comment: Isn't that Angular2?